# Trying to find column index via range name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on this spreadsheet and am running into massive difficulties. Essentially, I am trying to find the column index number that contains the range name "Average".

So, if "Average" is in column index 22, then 22 will be returned, etc.

```
Range("AA1").Select
Selection.Name = "Average"

Dim colNumber As Integer

colNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match("Average", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("1, Average"), 0)  'Average is a range name

Columns(colNumber).Insert
```

Each time I get different errors for this line, ranging from type mismatch to global_ failure:

`colNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match("Average", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("1, Average"), 0)`

I've searched everywhere looking for how to find a column index number based on a range name within a range, and I can't find anything. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-defining the range name by these lines of code:

```
Range("AA1").Select
Selection.Name = "Average"
```

In the remaining code you seem to just look for a text string "Average" in cell-content.

To get the column of the top-left corner of a range name named "Average" you would need:

```
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = ThisWorkbook.Names("Average").ReferstoRange.Cells(1,1).Column
```

Comment: Ok this makes so much more sense now. The ReferstoRange method was the missing key I think. Thanks Jkpieterse!